# How to configure the gzip compressor for JSON response?

Tags: 8

I am implementing REST resource endpoints to expose drupal content. Request to fetch this content is accepting gzip compressor but in response headers, this is not available.

[image]

I confirmed whether gzip is enabled in the server or not by viewing any content. In node view I can see the `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the Response headers. I tried manually to add headers in REST resource like below:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
```

But this is leading to below error:

[image]

Can anybody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of research on this site lead me to this answer, which should help you setting up your server.

The header are just a declaration of a capacity, but if compression is not set up on the server(apache, nginx...), you will have this error.

[How and where would I be able to enable/disable gzip compression?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108870/how-and-where-would-i-be-able-to-enable-disable-gzip-compression)